# Поддержка версий

Tags: android, eclipse

Где в eclipse задается поддержка версий android? Или она только при создании проекта?

Comment: Это я прекрасно знаю, пункт называется Minimum Required SDK, вот это я и хочу увидеть где находится минимальная версия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле `manifest.xml`.

`minsdkversion 4` соответствует андроиду 1.6, 7 - 2.1, 8 - 2.2 и т.д.